# QT How to click on the screen and make a Label appear in the same position?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm writing code to display labels on the screen and then drag and drop those labels. But when I use `show()` for those appear on the screen, I create multiple windows, each one of then with one label.

I already tried to use layouts and add a widget in this every time that i click with the mouse on the screen, but i cant place then in a custom position, only side a side or one in the top of the other.

```cpp
else if(event->button()==Qt::RightButton)
{
    QLabel *child = new QLabel;
    child->setPixmap(QPixmap("C:/Users/ILHA4/Desktop/boat.png"));
    child->move(event->x(),event->y());
    child->show();
}
```

This is from the `mousePressEvent()` function, and I don't know how to put all these labels that I create when I click on the screen in the same window.

Comment: QWidget without parent becomes top level window.

Comment: so how can i do it? to make the widget have a parent?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't found the c++ tag =(

Comment: change `QLabel *child = new QLabel;` to `QLabel *child = new QLabel(this);`

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! thanks dude S2